# Rails way to union semi related data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following snippet to get all ClassTypes that a user has Subscribed to, as well as all the ClassTypes that the user has not Subscribed to, and display it in the UI. I am using the Subscription model as it saves the historical price which I display to the user.

```
@subscriptions = Subscription.where(user_id: current_user.id)
subscription_ids = @subscriptions.pluck(:class_type_id)
classtypes_not_subscribed_to = ClassType.where.not(id: subscription_ids)

classtypes_not_subscribed_to.each do |c|
        @subscriptions << Subscription.new(class_type_id: c.id, price: c.price)
    end
```

This however feels like a hack, what is the Rails way to do something like this?

Below is a screenshot of what I am trying to do functionality wise (if the user is not subscribed then let them subscribe, else let them cancel):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you the creation of scopes for your classes, it really makes the code much cleaner

```
    class Subscription
      named_scope :of, lambda {|user| {
        conditions: { user_id: user.id }
      } }
    end

    class ClassType
      named_scope :not_subscribed_for, lambda { |user|
        subscribed_classes_ids = Subscription.of(user).all.pluck(:class_type_id)
        { conditions: ["id NOT IN ?", subscribed_classes_ids] }
      }
    end
```

And then you would just call `ClassType.not_subscribed_for(some_user)`. And of course, the names are arbitrary